# PayPal TransactionSearch API: How to page through results if there are more than 100 matches

Tags: paypal

As described in the doc (https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/TransactionSearch_API_Operation_SOAP/), "The maximum number of transactions that can be returned from a TransactionSearch API call is 100."

So what is the recommended approached if I want to page through all the results?
I suppose I could shorten the time rage until it fits less than 100 results but that's really lame...

Comment: I agree that it's very lame.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

When transaction search has more than 100 transaction, PayPal sends 100 transaction with ACK as `SuccessWithWarning`.

When you get ACK = SuccessWithWarning, get timestamp of last transaction from the result.
Now make another transaction search call with STARTDATE equal to last transaction's timestamp.

Continue till you get ACK = Success.

Hope this helps.

Comment: That sounds reasonable and I will try that, but, is it actually documented anywhere?

Comment: I think I found it actually: https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/express-checkout/ht_searchRetrieveTransactionData-curl-etc/

Comment: In my Case, Paypal-NVP returns the newest items for the selected timespan, so i have to set the enddate to the last items date, but it works - only backwards.

Comment: If you do this, you get the "last" transaction twice (clearer: all transactions in the same second of the last fetched transaction). You have to take care that this is not a problem. PayPals date format does not include milliseconds, therefore you only can hope that your business does not receive more than 100 transactions in two seconds ;-)

Comment: More specifically, if you get L_ERRORCODE0 == 11002, then the results have been truncated. There could be other causes for ACK=SuccessWarning